# Can pgpool manage sessions since the server application keep connections after they're no longer active?

Tags: postgresql, delphi-2010, datasnap, pgpool

I have an server applications with datasnap and delphi 2010 (this version have some problems managing sessions), and I have to terminate the idle sessions in postgres once a day.

I've installed pgpool but it doesn't make any difference, so, did I configured it wrong or since it's the server that keep those connections alive pgpool can't do the 'magic' to manage that?

Comment: Did you try the connection_life_time and client_idle_limit parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like pgpool only works if the client and server are the same OS....